# Refactoring a "show-list" function in lisp

Tags: refactoring, lisp, common-lisp

I have written a function called "show-list" which passes all the tests below

```
(defun show-list (l)
  (cond ((atom l) 
         (format t "~s" l))
        (t (format t "[")
           (do ((lst l (cdr lst)))
               ((null lst) (format t"]"))
             (cond ((atom lst)
               (format t ". ")
               (format t "~s" lst)
               (format t "]")
               (return-from show-list))
              (t (show-list (car lst))
                 (when (cdr lst)
                   (format t " "))))))))

(define-test show-list
  (assert-prints "[A B C]" (show-list '(a b c)))
  (assert-prints "[[[A B] C] D]" (show-list '(((a b) c) d)))
  (assert-prints "[A [B C]]" (show-list '(a (b c))))
  (assert-prints "[A . B]" (show-list '(a . b)))
  (assert-prints "[A B C . D]" (show-list '(a b c . d)))
  (assert-prints "A" (show-list 'a))
  (assert-prints "12" (show-list 12))
  (assert-prints "NIL" (show-list nil))
  (assert-prints "[NIL]" (show-list '(nil)))
  (assert-prints "[[[A]]]" (show-list '(((a)))))
  (assert-prints "[[A] . B]" (show-list '((a) . b)))
  )
```

but I've gotten a feedback saying

```
(defun show-list (l)
  (cond ((or (null l) (atom l)) 

;;; "You don't need an `or` here"*

         (format t "~s" l))
        (t (format t "[")
           (do ((lst l (cdr lst)))
               ((null lst) (format t"]"))

;;; Though `null` is the usual test for end of lists, it's not the right one 
;;; here, because the lists might not end with `NIL`. Use a different equally 
;;; simple test, that applies to all valid lists you want to handle. Then 
;;; check in the exit branch what needs to happen before finishing.

             (cond ((atom lst)
               (format t ". ")
               (format t "~s" lst)
               (format t "]")
               (return-from show-list))

;;; You don't need to bury a `return` inside the `do` body. Use the exit test 
;;; of the `do`. That's what it's for.

              (t (show-list (car lst))
                 (when (cdr lst)
                   (format t " "))))))))

;;; You won't need a conditional in the loop to handle spaces between 
;;; elements, if you do the first element before the loop.
```

I've been trying to refactor it for hours but I feel like I'm wasting time and not making any progress...

Comment: Do you have any example of where you code would fail?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are walking a tree it seems awkward to have loops in your code. It should basically only be (1) test if we have an atom, else (2) recurse on `car` and `cdr`.

Here's an example that uses only recursion, no `return-from`:

```
(defun show-list (l &optional (is-car t))
  (cond
   ((atom l)
    (unless is-car (format t ". "))
    (format t "~s" l))
   (t
    (when is-car (format t "["))
    (show-list (car l) t)
    (let ((cd (cdr l)))
      (unless (null cd)
        (format t " ")
        (show-list cd nil)))
    (when is-car (format t "]")))))
```

The only piece of "magic" is the additional parameter which helps remembering whether we're currently processing the `car` or the `cdr` of a cons cell.